# phpexcel getDrawingCollection - some images are not recognized

Tags: php, image, collections, drawing, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to parse through my excel file. And my file is having images in each row.I am using "getDrawingCollection" function to get all the images in the excel file. It works fine overall. But some of the images are not recognized by the getDrawingCollection function. Do i need to change anything in my code?

```
 $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($uploadfile);

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    foreach ($objWorksheet->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
        $string = $drawing->getCoordinates();
        $coordinate = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString($string);


        if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing) {
                          //copy image
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing) {
```

Won't pick up "memory drawings"

You might want to use

```
if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_BaseDrawing) {
```

instead; something like:

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );

        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $extension = 'png';
    } else {
        $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(),'r');
        $imageContents = '';

        while (!feof($zipReader)) {
            $imageContents .= fread($zipReader,1024);
        }
        fclose($zipReader);
        $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
    }
    $myFileName = '00_Image_'.++$i.'.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents($myFileName,$imageContents);
}
```

Comment: But my problem is, the "$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection()" function itself not recognizing some images in my excel sheet. For ex : I have 3 images in my worksheet. But this foreach loop executes only one time. The other 2 images are not recognized. Is there any problem with my images?

Comment: Then I haven't a clue without seeing the actual file. Aside from charts, that have their own collection; and shapes that aren't supported by PHPExcel, I don't know what type of images aren't added to the drawingCollection

Comment: http://jmp.sh/ISqbA8E This the sample excel file with images. Here the first 2 images are not recognized.

Comment: Now i found the images (which are not recognized by phpExcel are shapes. But looks like images). How to convert these shapes to images?

Comment: You'd need to write some logic in the Reader to parse shape data from the file that's being loaded, and some logic in core PHPExcel to maintain those shapes